# Como estilizar um selec option

Tags: html, css, dropdownlist

Boa tarde galera,

Estou buscando uma forma de estilizar um select mas nao estou conseguindo, e também nao estou conseguindo achar material na internet para fazer isso, se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

E o seguinte eu quero colocar uma parte em negrito e a outra deixar normal tipo:

```
<select name="">
      <option value=""><strong>Nome</strong> - Nome</option>
      <option value=""><strong>Nome1</strong> - Nome1</option>
      <option value=""><strong>Nome2</strong> - Nome2</option>
</select>
```

O **strong** ou o **b** colocado assim nao funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não seja possível estilizar, pois isso é renderizado internamente pelo navegador, ou seja, em alguns navegadores pode funcionar, e outros não. Você pode tentar estilizar uma option por inteira.

```
option:nth-child(1), option:nth-child(4) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078927/css-select-dropdown-bold-on-some-options

Você tambem pode utilizar [Select2](https://select2.org/dropdown), permite você construir dropdown mais complexos

Comment: Nao teria outras formas para fazer isso? a minha finalidade e deixar so uma parte mesmo independente da forma.

Comment: Se for algo realmente muito necessário eu recomendo usar Select2, todos os frameworks modernos em javascript possuem implementações melhores do dropdown, mas o HTML puro não permite customização

Comment: Segundo a documentação, o valor interno dentro do option deve ser somente texto: 
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element

Comment: Você pode tambem usar optgroup para deixar mais organizado https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup